# Using a Raspberry Pi as a "desktop" for a UHF RFID device

Tags: rfid

I am trying to use a UHF RFID reader and they are mostly desktop compatible, can I use my Raspberry Pi as that "desktop" and if possible, can you recommend a particular UHF RFID reader?

Comment: It is possible to use a RPi as a "desktop" in the case that you describe, providing that the manufacturer of the UHF RFID device provides a driver pre-compiled for the OS that you are using (i.e. (in all probability) a Linux variant, unless you use Windows 10 IoT) and that the driver has been compiled for ARM (the processor that the RPi uses) - or the source code is available. Regarding which reader... which ones have you looked at already? [_Shopping suggestion_ type questions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) are, unfortunately, generally considered to be off-topic here.

Comment: As @Greenonline point asking for hardware recomendations would be better in http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [RFID system that integrates with Raspberry Pi Model B?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/rfid-system-that-integrates-with-raspberry-pi-model-b)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use a RPi as a "desktop" in the case that you describe, so long as the manufacturer of the UHF RFID (or, for that matter, any other USB) device provides:

- a driver pre-compiled for the OS that you are using (i.e. (in all probability) a Linux variant, unless you use Windows 10 IoT) and;
- the driver has been compiled for ARM (the processor that the RPi uses), or;
- the source code for the driver is available, in which case you can compile it yourself.

Regarding which UHF RFID reader could be recommended... which ones have you looked at already? [*Shopping suggestion* type questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) are, unfortunately, generally considered to be off-topic here.

Having said that, you may want to take a look at the thread, [Raspberry RFID UHF](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=31454), which seems to mention the Cottonwood device, although it repeats the fact that the device works on Windows, but not on the Pi - probably due to the lack of a driver. However, it could be possible to employ the device, using the UART as an interface, en lieu of the USB port:

> I bought this Cottonwood kit: http://www.soliddepot.com/index.php?mai
>   ... cts_id=232
>
> The AS399x reader module and the 8dbi antenna.
>
> My reader was configured to use USB, which worked fine on windows but
>   I was not able to read/write over USB on the raspberry pi. They
>   included the 'debug' cable, and was able to follow the guide to flash
>   the reader to do UART.
>
> I now have the Raspberry Pi connected via UART, and after disabling
>   the 'serial console' on the Pi, can attach a Python serial script to
>   ttyAMA0, send and receive commands.
>
> Writing the version command (string1 = "\x10\x03\x01") returns the
>   version data as documented and writing the 'read card' string (string2
>   = "\x37\x05\x01\x02\x06") does return a string that looks somewhat IDish.
>
> I think what I need now is to figure out how to clear buffers, read
>   antenna strength, read frequency info, then tune it up to read ID tags
>   to fit my application.

Also, take look at [the answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/rfid-system-that-integrates-with-raspberry-pi-model-b#answer-22120) to [RFID system that integrates with Raspberry Pi Model B?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/rfid-system-that-integrates-with-raspberry-pi-model-b)